# Repeating a word in a sentence

Tags: research

I've just installed a tool for my research documents and I found out I use a lot of repeating words.

- ... is ***a*** way where ***a*** developer can ...
- Since ***the*** beginning of ***the*** web, using a ...

Is this bad practice or is this tool just trying to stay on the cautious side.
Or are there nice workarounds?

(English is not my first language)

Comment: This question is better asked on [writers.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with repeating words in the same sentence, though if you always repeat words in your writing, it can become boring. In the examples you mentioned, *a* and *the* are articles and are therefore very common, so you don't need to worry about them. Of course, you can rewrite sentences like 'John loves ice cream, so John always eats them' to 'John loves ice cream, so he always eats them'.

Comment: If you wait a while, you will get the privilege to post comments.